# Filtering an aliased column

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I have the following query in MS-Access, which runs fine:

```
SELECT A1.LRN, A1.StartDate, A1.Destination, 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 A2.StartDate
    FROM testEnrolment As A2
    WHERE A2.LRN = A1.LRN AND A2.StartDate > A1.StartDate
    ORDER BY A2.StartDate
) As NextStartDate, 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 B2.Destination
    FROM testEnrolment As B2
    WHERE B2.LRN = A1.LRN AND B2.StartDate > A1.StartDate
    ORDER BY B2.StartDate
) As NextDestination
FROM testEnrolment As A1
```

The 2 aliased columns `NextStartDate`, `NextDestination` get their data from the `StartDate` and `Destination` fields of the next record for the current `LRN`.

So if the table **testEnrolment** has this data:

```
LRN    StartDate    Destination
--------------------------------
L0001  01/08/2014   Unemployed
L0001  02/08/2014   Education
L0001  03/08/2014   Unemployed
L0002  20/09/2014   Education
L0002  21/09/2014
```

The query will result in this:

```
LRN    StartDate   Destination  NextStartDate  NextDestination
--------------------------------------------------------------
L0001  01/08/2014  Unemployed   02/08/2014     Education
L0001  02/08/2014  Education    03/08/2014     Unemployed
L0001  03/08/2014  Unemployed
L0002  20/09/2014  Education    21/09/2014
L0002  21/09/2014
```

What I want to do next is filter the column alias `NextDestination` by records that are *not equal to* "Education".

A `WHERE` clause will not work on a column alias and I can't seem to get `HAVING` to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your sql into a sub query so you can filter on the aliases

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A1.LRN, A1.StartDate, A1.Destination, 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 A2.StartDate
    FROM testEnrolment As A2
    WHERE A2.LRN = A1.LRN AND A2.StartDate > A1.StartDate
    ORDER BY A2.StartDate
) As NextStartDate, 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 B2.Destination
    FROM testEnrolment As B2
    WHERE B2.LRN = A1.LRN AND B2.StartDate > A1.StartDate
    ORDER BY B2.StartDate
) As NextDestination
FROM testEnrolment As A1
) AS s
WHERE NextDestination <> 'Education'
```

Comment: Thanks - glad there's a simple solution :)